# Error starting uWSGI modular build: No such file or directory - /etc/uwsgi/ext/uwsgi/uwsgi.ruby

Tags: python, ruby, debian, uwsgi

I've install uWSGI, and I'm trying to start it in emperor mode. I've installed all the necessary dependencies, and the python plugin. The error is correct, there is no file by that name in that location. The error is below.

```
/usr/bin/uwsgi:4:in `exec': No such file or directory - /etc/uwsgi/ext/uwsgi/uwsgi.ruby (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/bin/uwsgi:4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I'm not sure what I did to cause the problem, but hopefully this helps someone out in the future.

I can see in the executable that it's looking for the file here:

```
cmd = File.expand_path "/etc/uwsgi/ext/uwsgi/uwsgi.ruby" //(edited to show the real path)
```

But this clearly isn't there. This could have something to do with not having ruby installed when I first configured uWSGI. So I solved the following by:

- Installing ruby
- Running `ruby extconf.rb`. `extconf.rb` is the only file in the directory it's searching in (`/etc/uwsgi/ext/uwsgi/`)

So, there it is. No idea why this happened, but this is what fixed it. If anyone can lend any information on the cause, that would be great.

Comment: I have installed uwsgi on my mac (10.13.6) and I get this error when trying to launch the MyApp example from https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/JWSGI.html. We will see.